# Include a .twig base template in a .php template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I use .twig templates on a website however I need to get pretty crafty with the logic on a few of the views. I dont think twig can handle this and its a piece of cake to do in PHP. (I'm not going to explain the details of what that is, just know its easy in PHP and I actually already have the code). The question is, can I include a .PHP template in base or parent templates that are of type .twig?

Example below (which does not work) - blah.html.php is a template which extends the base.html.twig template...

/some/web/directory/bundlename/Resources/views/blah/blah.html.php

```
<?php $view->extend('::base.html.twig') ?>

<?php $view['slots']->set('title', 'Welcome to nowhere!') ?>

<?php $view['slots']->start('body') ?>

    <div id="body">
        html stuff here, blah blah blah...
        <?php .... ?>
            complex php and html stuff, and so on...
        </php end....?> 
        you get the idea...
    </div>

<?php $view['slots']->stop() ?>
```

On the browser the code above renders all the .twig code in the base template as text in the browser (I.E. it does not get executed by the templating engine).

PS - yes I have both .twig and .php set in app/config/config.yml

```
templating:      { engines: ['twig', 'php'] }
```

---

Ok, here are the details of the "complex" stuff...
This is taken from a version of the site which was coded in Symfony 1.4 - Its being upgraded to Symfony 2 and we want to use all .twig

```
<?php foreach ($all_items as $item): ?>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        //<?php include_partial('global/item', array('item' => $item)) ?>

 <<< some code snipped out here >>>

    <td valign="top">
        <table border="1" width="100%">
        <?php echo $form->renderFormTag('memberitems/additem') ?>
        <?php echo $form['item_id']->render(array('value' => $item->getIid())) ?>
        <?php echo $form['user_id']->render(array('value' => 1)) ?>
        <?php echo $form['_csrf_token'] ?>
            <tr>
                <td width="50" colspan="2" align="center">Quantity<br><?php echo $form['quantity']->render() ?></td>
                <td width="50" colspan="2" align="center">Amount<br><?php echo $form['value']->render() ?></td>
                <td width="50" colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Add"></td>
            </tr>
        </form>

    <<< here is a complex portion, we're declaring a variable with a value >>>
    <<< cant do this with twig - from what I know... >>>

        <?php // determine if item is in registry - if so display "Currently Asking For:" ?>
        <?php $is_in_registry = false; ?>
        <?php foreach($member_items as $m_item): ?>
        <?php   if($m_item->getIid() == $item->getIid()): ?>
        <?php       if($is_in_registry == false): ?>
        <?php           $is_in_registry = true; ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="50" colspan="6" align="center"><br>Currently Asking For:</td>
                        </tr>
        <?php       endif ?>

        <?php echo $form->renderFormTag('memberitems/removeitem') ?>
        <?php echo $form['item_id']->render(array('value' => $item->getIid())) ?>
        <?php echo $form['user_id']->render(array('value' => 1)) ?>
        <?php echo $form['id']->render(array('value' => $m_item->getMIid())) ?>
        <?php echo $form['_csrf_token']->render() ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td width="50" colspan="4" align="center">
                                <?php echo $m_item->getMIqty()." @ ".$m_item->getMIval() ?>
                            </td>
                            <td width="50" colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Remove"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </form>
        <?php   endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: What sort of complex stuff? you could put it on a twig function or a macro.

Comment: Carlosz - I've updated the question with some detail on the complex stuff... This is just one example of what I call complex, and by complex I mean complex to .twig because I dont think twig was designed to handle logic like this. (I could be wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complex logic should really be put in the service layer in Symfony2. The templates should look clean and tidy for all the devs not familiar with PHP (e.g front-end developers).

However, I don't see anything in that template that couldn't be done in Twig. Here's the tricky part written in Twig to prove it:

```
{% set is_in_registry = false %}
{% for m_item in member_items %}

    {% if m_item.getIid == item.getIid %}
        {% if is_in_registry is false %}
            {% set is_in_registry = true %}
            <tr>
                {# you should use css for styling the td #}
                <td width="50" colspan="6" align="center"><br />Currently asking for:</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}

        {{ form.renderFormTag('memberitems/removeitem') }}
        {{ form.item_id.render({ value: item.getIid }) }}
        {{ form.user_id.render({ value: 1 }) }}
        {{ form.id.render({ value: m_item.getMIid }) }}
        {{ form._csrf_token.render }}

        <tr>
            <td width="50" colspan="4" align="center">
                {{ m_item.getMIqty ~ ' @ ' ~ m_item.getMIval }}
            </td>
            <td width="50" colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Remove"></td>
        </tr>
        {# didn't notice your form opening tag. I'm assuming you're dynamically generating it #}
        </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: gilden - thank you for the code above! I totall agree that the "tricky" stuff should not even be in the view. I was unaware that twig had the ability to declare variables, this might resolve 90% of the complex code. I should be able to move the other 10% out and into the service later.

Comment: @CocoaNoob Twig is quite powerful and with the extensibility provided there really is no limit. Just in case you haven't done it already, I suggest you read the (really short) [manual](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation) to get the best out of Twig.

Comment: Will do - I read the brief intro on the symfony.com site (  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html ) but not the info at ( http://twig.sensiolabs.org ). Thats up next! Thanks again!